# "Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port" appeared when I install extensions in "extensions.gnome.org"

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I want to know why the switch with ON/OFF has disappeared. And there appeared the message "Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port".
I remember it can be used normally before I installed the vpn lantern.
How can I resolve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because Mozilla has dropped the NPAPI support from Firefox. This affects many plugins like Siverlight, Acrobat, and Java as well as the GNOME integration plugin.

To get the GNOME website to work, you need to install `chrome-gnome-shell` a native host messaging application. To do this, open a new Terminal and type the following commands.

**For Ubuntu**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

**For Fedora**

```
dnf copr enable region51/chrome-gnome-shell
dnf install chrome-gnome-shell
```

**For Gentoo**

```
emerge -av gnome-extra/chrome-gnome-shell
```

Also, if you are using Firefox, make sure you have [GNOME Shell Integration Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/)  installed.

Comment: So great!This is the correct way to solve the problem.I solved it when I installed chrome-gnome-shell.